# SSAS: Error duplicate attribute key in processing Cube Dimension

Tags: duplicates, attributes, ssas, cube, dimension

There's dimension DimTable1 containing in Column1 a lot of duplicate values, NULL values and '' values. Processing the Cube fails with an error:

> Errors in the OLAP storage engine: A duplicate attribute key has been
> found when processing: Table: 'dwh_DimTable1', Column: 'Column1',
> Value: ''.

However it used to work properly with all this data before. And after I'd updated the '' values to 'default' it also processed successfully. The question is what's wrong with this data, why it allows duplicates, nulls but not empty strings? The Cube definition hasn't been changed recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null vales get converted to empty string.

as a test I'd try updating your column to be non empty string data and process data.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it is processed correctly when all '' are updated to non-empty strings. However the customer preferes to have them as is, like ''. And it used to work fine with '' before. I can't figure out what is technically wrong.

Comment: So has the source data changed, or,has allow duplicates been disabled?

Comment: No, duplicates are still enabled, there're plenty of dupies in this column. NULLs are what is really new to it. Previously only '' were there, but recently records with NULLs have been loaded. So it looks like the Cube accepts either NULLs or '', thank you!